# insert into a SQL table

Tags: php, sql

Hi, I'm currently trying to add data into my SQL table using php I can't seem to see where I'm going wrong here, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ModuleId in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined index: Title in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined index: CreditLevel in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined index: CreditPoints in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined index: Status in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 70

Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 72

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 72
```

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit") {

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","useername ","password ","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


    $insert = "INSERT INTO module (ModuleId, Title, CreditLevel, CreditPoints, Status, Award)

    VALUES ('".$_POST['ModuleId']."','".$_POST['Title']."','".$_POST['CreditLevel']."','".$_POST['CreditPoints']."','".$_POST['Status']."','".$_POST['Award']."')";

    $add_member = mysql_query($insert);


 ?>
```

Can someone please help? :/

Comment: Simple => `mysql_query` <= ahem (*that's a clue*)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_`. These are two different API's.

Comment: You have a list of seven explicit error messages and you can't see where you're going wrong?

Comment: *Sniff sniff* => [**I smell injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Answer (score -1):

You've used `mysql_query()` when you should be using `mysqli_query()` for a start.

Comment: This was already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: i have changed mysql_query() to mysqli_query() and now im getting the following message Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in N:\ftp\compc\d11os\Project\addModule.php on line 70

Comment: @user3605679 Ok. Google that error.